# React Native - Integration of camera and photo upload in one screen

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-image-picker

I am trying to find a library or a way to implement the camera and upload pictures in one screen like it is on IOS or android camera. For example you open the camera app and you get to take the photo or choose from gallery.

Is there a way to do this?

I know that react-native-image-picker can launch the camera and photo library but on different states and screens.

Comment: If if this isn’t possible, I just want an answer, to know what to do.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @FrédéricFaraWat I didn't :( if you ever do find a solution please share it.